# ANTLR4 Nested modes?

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm attempting to parse the following string:

```
<<! variable, my_variable, A description of my variable !>>
```

From the reading I've been doing here, I believe I need to use modes to distinguish between the lexers for the literal string 'variable', the variable name (my_variable), and the variable description.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure how to structure this.  Is it possible to nest modes?  Is there a better/smarter way to organize my lexer rules?

```
lexer grammar VariableLexer;

variableMarkdown : DELIMITER_OPEN SPACE VARIABLE COMMA SPACE variable_name COMMA SPACE description SPACE DELIMITER_CLOSE;

description : WORDS ;

variable_name : ID ;

DELIMITER_OPEN : '<<!' ;
DELIMITER_CLOSE : '!>>';

COMMA : ',' ;
SPACE : ' ' ;

VARIABLE : 'variable' -> pushMode(VariableName);

mode VariableName;
ID : LOWERCASE ( LOWERCASE | NUMBER | UNDERSCORE )* -> pushMode(VariableDescription) ;

mode VariableDescription;
WORDS : ( UPPERCASE | LOWERCASE | NUMBER | SPACE )+ -> popMode;


fragment LOWERCASE : 'a'..'z' ;
fragment UPPERCASE : 'A'..'Z' ;
fragment UNDERSCORE : '_' ;
fragment NUMBER : '0'..'9' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First - you can't have parser rules in lexer grammar - parser rules start with small letter, lexer ones with capital.

I'd do it like so (may not be correct syntax but you'll get the idea):

```
//default mode is implicitly defined by (or in) ANTLR4
VARIABLE : 'variable' (' ')* ',' -> mode(mode_VariableName);
...
mode mode_VariableName;
//define token with anything ending with comma, many ways to do this...
fragment varNameFrag: [a-zA-Z_0-9]; 
VARIABLE_NAME: varNameFrag varNameFrag* (' ')* ',' -> mode(mode_varDesc);
mode mode_varDesc;
//similar again for variable description
VAR_DESC: //I'll write just a comment here but should more or less match anything except
END_VAR: '!>>' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
```

Basically in this way you are jumping to modes you need instead of pushing and popping.